# Getting entries from one MySQL table, optionally counting respective ID's in other

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I've tried to find a solution to this for a long time, read a lot of topics about PIVOT, JOIN, etc., but still can't seem to find a solution, so I really need your help.

I'm programming a thumbs up/down system for comments. So, I want to list all my comments AND their current vote sum, plus show whether I (as of userID in comments_votes table) have already voted or not, and all of that, if possible (which I assume) within one SQL query.

I have two MySQL tables:

1) comments

- commentID
- comment
- userID
- topicID

2) comments_votes

- commentID
- userID
- vote (= 1 or -1, for thumb up or down).

**<<<<< PART 1: Total Vote Sum >>>>>**

In the first part, I want to show the current sum of all votes which would be the SUM(vote) for that specific commentID. The vote sum could should work for every comment, even if a comment hasn't received any votes yet (so if there's no entry in second table for that commentID). So if there's zero entries for that comment in the comments_vote table, then the vote sum is 0.

One of the major problems I encountered here was that I do NOT only want to get the comments for which there is also a vote! This is for example the reason why a simple "," between the two tables and a.commentID=b.commentID didn't work (because that one only returned the ones where theres matching entries for both tables). For the pivot table I never really got it working. The JOIN function also doesn't seem to do the job. Any idea how I could fix this?

**<<<<< PART 2: Have I voted already? >>>>>**

So for the second part, I want to determine whether my userID is already in the comments_votes table for each comment. In a way that if I have already voted for that comment, I won't be enabled via PHP/HTML to vote again.

-

Right now, I got it working by using one Mysql while(...) and then two functions within this loop, which is of course a terrible solution as it kills site speed. My goal is to get all of that in one SQL query, or some other alternative if that's faster. I need the fastest-running solution.

Your help is GREATLY appreciated! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
select
  c.commentID
, sum(case when cvuser.vote is null then ifnull(cv.vote,0) else 0 end) commentScore
, sum(case when cvuser.vote is null then abs(ifnull(cv.vote,0)) else 0 end) totalCommentScore
, sum(ifnull(cvuser.vote,0))!=0 userHasVoted -- 1 if user has voted, 0 if has not voted
from
  comments c
  left outer join comments_votes cv using (commentID)
  left outer join comments_votes cvuser on c.commentID=cvuser.commentID and cv.userID=<INSERT USER ID HERE>
group by c.commentID
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That does definitely come closer to what I need! The userHasVoted part works like a charm, the only bug there is, is that he seems to count some entries twice for the commentScore. For example, I have one comment with 2 positive votes and 1 negative votes (so: 1,-1,1). So in reality, the score is 1, out of 3 votes. But the query gives me 5 as the current score out of 7 votes. I don't really understand why? Is it in relation to the ifnull() ? Do you know a solution to this? Thanks again, your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ahh: I think it's double counting votes for the comment because of the second left outer join. I think I've addressed that now but I'm not sure.

Comment: Indeed, removing one solves the problem, but unfortunately that doesn't solve the entire problem. Do you have any idea how I could completely solve it? I'm really stuck here :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Part 1:** 
The comma and the JOIN approach both refer to a more specific SQL function called "INNER JOIN," which only brings back the shared records. If you want to bring back all of one table and a portion of another, you want a LEFT JOIN or a RIGHT JOIN.

This is the best resource I've seen about the joins: [Visual Representation of Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

**Part 2:**
If you just do a SELECT * WHERE `user_id` = [your user id], you should be ok. If speed is really an issue, consider doing a column index on your `user_id` column in your database. That should eliminate any speed issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The LEFT Join works (as explained by Kevin Postlewaite here above). Also, I didn't know that with the column index and the linked to the performance. I've made a few researches and that helped me a lot! Thanks again!!